# How do I configure a WCF web service for Basic authentication, but expose metadata with anonymous authentication

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl

I have a WCF SOAP-1.2 web service hosted in IIS that is using HTTP Basic Auth via a customBinding specification.  In dev environments, it uses only HTTP.  In QA, it uses HTTP and HTTPS.  In prod, it uses HTTPS transport only.

Right now the WSDL is exposed by a serviceBehavior tag, rather simply, like this (using httpsGetEnabled as appropriate):

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

I would like to enable anonymous access to the WSDL/schemas only, as they currently require Basic Auth as does the actual service.  How does one do that?  I've dug around on MSDN, and found some [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) pointing to use of a webHttpBinding for the metadata specifically, but I can't seem to get it to forget about Basic Auth:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding" httpGetBindingConfiguration="metadatabinding" />
...
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="metadatabinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
...
</bindings>
```

In using the above tweaked metadata tags, I am prompted for Basic credentials in the browser when pulling up `http://someserver/service.svc?wsdl` (and those names have been sanitized).

In IIS, I have enabled anonymous and Basic auth for the site/application, such that the bindings ultimately control the credential requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, I actually did not change the IIS application configuration as I stated that I did in the question.  To make the second, expanded web.config above work properly, you need to enable Anonymous *and* Basic Auth inside of IIS in the "Authentication" section of either a site or application so that at the application level, both are available.  By using a binding for the actual service which has an `authenticationScheme="Basic"`, the service is authenticated while the metadata is not.

I'm surprised this is not as directly documented; most helpful tips that I could find on other social sites or SO has suggested using a separate application or static resources for WSDLs and schemas, as opposed to the loosening access to the WCF generated metadata.

Answer (score 1):

The `authenticationScheme` attribute change did the trick for me as well (from @Greg's answer).

However, I have a self-hosted service, so I added it to the App.config file instead.

This defines both HTTPS and Basic Authentication to the serviceMetaData endpoint:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HttpsAndBasicAuthentication" >
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://localhost:8000/CalculatorService" />
      <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Basic"/>  
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Note that this behavior has to be referenced in the `<service>` element using the `behaviorConfiguration` attribute.